# Attaching $2$-dimensional cell to $D^2$ gives the space $S^2/(x\sim -x)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I am studying Algebraic Topology, and right now I am going through cell-attachment, which I have a pretty hard time to grasp. An "example" they give in the book is:

---

**Example:**

Define $X$ to be the space obtained from $S^2$ by identifying antipodal points on the equator, then it is easy to see that $X$ can be obtained by attaching a $2$-dimensional cell to $D^2$.

---

I suppose this should be easy, but it isn't for me, so I would be really happy if someone could help me through this example and how to define the map. Since I don't even know where (and how) to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $D^2$ and let the attaching map be $e:\partial D^2 \to \partial D^2$ be the quotient map, as in $z \mapsto z^2 $ as complex numbers.

Also note that if the attaching map were identity, we would just recover $S^2$.

Comment: when you attach a cell, you attach its boundary.

Comment: @TsemoAristide my apologies, i both misread the question and said something silly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andres. This looks like an answer I am happy with. :) Anyhow, I will have to take a closer look at this tomorrow (and maybe also have some questions by then) since it's in the middle of the night here and I am starting to become... tired. ;)

Comment: @AndresMejia Probably a silly question, but why do you choose to map $-x$ to $x$ and not $x$ to $-x$? :)

Comment: Dear Andres, yes that's quite okay with me and I have deleted my now irrelevant previous comment.